# Write-Output from variable showing "at curly brace" notation value

Tags: powershell, variables

I'm more of a Linux bash shell guy and am running up against something in PowerShell that is puzzling me. I want to extract a list of user names from AD in a foreach loop and perform a certain operation on them.

At this point I'm simply concerned about whether I'm pulling the correct string before I run any important operation based on that string. Here is what I'm running as a test (details in square brackets removed for privacy):

```bsh
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
foreach ($x in (Get-ADUser -Filter * -Server "[host]" -SearchBase '[mybase]' | Select-Object SamAccountName)) {
    Write-Output "Alias is: $x"
}
```

So the deal is, if I leave off the double quotes in the `Write-Output` statement it looks great and will print:

```
Alias is:
username1
Alias is:
username2
Alias is:
username3
```

It injects a newline before each value though, which I'd rather remove/strip from the string.

But inside of double quotes I instead get:

```
Alias is: @{SamAccountName=username1}
Alias is: @{SamAccountName=username2)
Alias is: @{SamAccountName=username3}
```

I'm not sure how to extract the value I'm looking at from this. What am I looking at here? Is this something I need to dereference, or something in an array I need to extract? Or is my variable value actually an object and not a string and I need to somehow do a `ToString()` operation on it (or equivalent)?

Comment: `Select-Object SamAccountName` -> `Select-Object -Expand SamAccountName`

Comment: Ah, so indeed it is an object (as I should have inferred from the command Select-Object), and expand pulls the string out of it. It's always something simple. Thanks!

Comment: I don't actually think this is a duplicate as it is specific to Select-Object and the linked-to alternate question does not so much as mention the Expand parameter, potentially confusing other viewers who happen upon this question. I can see how the output notation overlaps, but nothing else. I mean, I got my answer and am happy with it, but you may want to think about what exactly was a duplicate and how I would have found that other thread using the search feature on this site prior to posting my own (which I did). If someone types "at curly bracket" on Google mine will likely be indexed.

Comment: The problem described in that question is exactly the same as yours, and the answers, particularly the one from mklement0, describe the solution to that problem.

Comment: Oh, interesting, I see that mklement0 mentions -ExpandProperty and not -Expand. I'm guessing the latter is a shorter form of the former. I see what you're saying now though.

Comment: Yes. Parameter names in PowerShell can be shortened as long as they remain unique. `-ExpandProperty` is the same as `-ExpandPr`, or `-Expand`, or even `-Exp`. However, `-Ex` or `-E` will not work, b/c there's another parameter named `-ExcludeProperty`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is here:

```bsh
Select-Object SamAccountName
```

it returns an object with `SamAccountName` property. If you want the value only, use 
`-ExpandProperty`:

```bsh
Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName
```